# pass input attribute data to other input function parameter - angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to pass ng-disabled data to other input function parameter:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in properties">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkDisable(isDisable)">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="properties[$index].isDisabled">
 </div>
```

plunkr: [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0b9oaNvwhi5P9Ncqo4XD?p=preview)

Comment: Do you mean something like this `ng-click="checkDisable(properties[$index].isDisabled)"` ?

Comment: You have to add `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat` to access the value of `$index` in your `html`

Comment: Its related to DOM attribute.Yiou should use directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the item value in the loop

```
<div ng-repeat="item in properties track by $index">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkDisable(item.isDisabled)">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="item.isDisabled">
 </div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mHME2Mvc7tof2CJxNYaW?p=preview)